# Issue with cursor jumping to last line on editing textArea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

**Problem Statement:**

I'm trying to build this component where user can enter a dollar amount, press enter and can continue to enter more stuff.

**Issue:**

> Whenever we enter an amount say 12345 press enter and enter 20000 and
> go back to edit the previous value (12345), **the cursor jumps to the last line**.

**Root cause:**

I figured that this is happening due to the `getValue` function in the code (Disabling this makes it perfect).

**Demo:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/money-input-example-forked-3m03e?file=/src/components/MoneyInputList.jsx:165-173

Can someone help me identify/fix what I'm doing wrong? I want to be able to edit any line (format it) without cursor jumping around.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: checking it out right now, just to note, if you go up with arrow keys it allows you to type 3 numbers, then push you. Odd behaviour really

Comment: You can clearly note that when value is changed, it moves to bottom. When value is not changed it doesn't move cursor.

Answer (score 0):

In **textarea** if you update the value, the cursor will be moved to the end. If you want to maintain the cursor position you can save it before changing the value property and then update it once changed.

Before modification

```
savedPosition = textarea.selectionEnd
```

After modification

```
textarea.selectionEnd = savedPosition
```

Consider the string

$ 123

Cursor is between one and two **position - 3**, now, If I type 4, new cursor position will be **position - 4**. And string will be

$ 1,423

When pasting this, old cursor position is 4(after insertion), and since the comma was added before three, the cursor position was increased by 1. You must set the cursor as 5 after doing your change.
Since react updates the textarea asynchronously, and I am unfamiliar with that I am not able to provide a solution. But save cursor position before, and keep track of the changes you make and transform cursor position accordingly, finally update cursor position once you modify text area value.

Comment: it doesnt move to end if you put a simple state. this is different

Comment: In fact, you actually have to transform the cursor position based on the changes done to the text. I think if you apply this, you will arrive at a solution

Comment: Could you give me an example? I'm so confused. would appreciate some inputs.  This is what makes SO sooo good.

Comment: There are three types of scenarios where the content of the textarea changes without user input.
1. Adding/Updating comma position when numbers are typed
2. Adding dollar for new Line
3. Special characters are removed
4. Lets ignore the [a-z] characters being added case
In all these cases the cursor moves to the end. Try this. Line one `$ 12` Line 2 `$ 123` Now go up, and start typing numbers. Note that when comma is added the cursor moves. After that, all typing(at end of first line) updates comma position, hence cursor is moved. If you type at start, content adds after 3 chars.

Comment: This is actually quite a tricky issue since, you actually wont know where the commas are inserted. A function gives you the computed output. So you will have to use a diff tool. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7ghntL9/3/) I have solved cursor issue when adding `$ `, but for comma adding it seems to be more complex. Good luck